# Is there a better way to display % in Android

Tags: java, android

Currently, I am displaying a value as a Percent by simply setting text as below:

```
mInterestRateEditText.setText(i + "%");
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have tried with DecimalFormat method like this:

```
private String displayPerc(int perc) {
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#%");
     return df.format(perc);
}
```

But for some reasons when i = 1 it displays 100%.

Is there a better way to display % other than concatenating the symbol at the end?

Thanks

Comment: When you look to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html) you can see: `%  Prefix or suffix  Yes  Multiply by 100 and show as percentage `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a string in strings.xml

```
<string name="percentage">%1$f %</string>
```

and set it in your code with

```
mInterestRateEditText.setText(getString(R.string.percentage, i));
```

**EDIT :** To do it the decimal format way, do

```
private String displayPerc(int perc) {
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#'%'");
  return df.format(perc);
}
```

put '%' instead of %. Normal % will Multiply by 100 and show as percentage. Check this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: is that not the same way as just concatenating the % at the end of the string?

Comment: @x10sion May be not for a percentage, but for sure a monetary amount or similar would be displayed differently in different languages. Having externalized strings and their formatting as suggested here can help you with internationalization.

Comment: I think the second percentage symbol should be encoded with `&#37;` to prevent problems with string formatting.

Comment: Also, OP is using integers, so using `d` is more appropriate than `f`